# Build wp8 with cordova not working and show Silverlight 4 SDK not installed

Tags: silverlight, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'v tried everything I found with no success! I can build for android with no problems. As you can see this is what I get

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQIt4.png

I have:
Cordova 3.6.3
silverlight sdk installed
Visual Studio 2013
both C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and npm in my PATH (system vars.)

I have connect my VS to TFS and add new "Build Definition" and change the the default template MSBuild Platform to X86 (I have no idea how this has anything to do with cordova cli!)

All I need is to build my project, I have nothing to do with VS2013. and btw I didn't install WP8.0 SDK as the VS2013 comes with 8.1 SDK which is what I want. however I don't know why its going to the v8.0 and not the v8.1 (see the red line in the image)!.

Any suggestions? or some step by step tutorial I can follow to see where im doing wrong.

Comment: Okay I figured it out :D "that was so stupid of me!"

wp8 = windows phone 8 "ONLY"
windows = "wp 8.1 and win 8.1

which is what I want and what I been preparing for!